# function processing PHP

Tags: php, regex, url-rewriting, e-commerce, php-5.2

in following function

```
public static function ToDepartment($departmentId, $page = 1)
{
$link = self::CleanUrlText(Catalog::GetDepartmentName($departmentId)) .
'-d' . $departmentId . '/';
if ($page > 1)
$link .= 'page-' . $page . '/';
return self::Build($link);
}
```

there is a line

```
$link = self::CleanUrlText(Catalog::GetDepartmentName($departmentId)) .
'-d' . $departmentId . '/';
```

I want to know will `self:CleanUrlText()` will be evaluated first or `Catalog:GetDepartmentName` will be evaluated first

if `Catalog:GetDepartmentName`  is evaluated first then, I have a confusion,
what purpose does URL cleaning solve,
if I am visiting a page such as `http://localhost/tshirtshop/visit@@@-the-zoo-d2/`
then .htaccess is handling the URL ReWriting part,
where d2 will get converted to DepartmentId=2 and internally in all code logic I will use DepartmentId which is an INT , then why CleanURL function is required
The code is given [here](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=FTZxXyXrFtUC&lpg=PA100&ots=UJmwl4z8fc&dq=smarty%20function%20load%20parameter%20object&pg=PA201#v=onepage&q=smarty%20function%20load%20parameter%20object&f=true)

Answer (score 0):

1st: Catalog::GetDepartmentName
2nd: self::CleanUrlText